# How to theme a node form from my custom module?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have a node type with machine name "resource", and I'm trying to theme it in my module "modulename".

I've tried doing this:

```
function modulename_theme() {
  return array(
    'resource_node_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      // 'template' => 'resource-node-form',
      // 'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'modulename'),
    ),
  );
}

//I've tried both functions, getting nothing

function theme_resource_node_form($variables) {
  dsm($variables);
  return 'Testing';
}

function modulename_resource_node_form($variables) {
  dsm($variables);
  return 'Testing';
}
```

I've cleared cache, nothing happens. I've also tried with templating approach:

```
function modulename_theme() {
  return array(
    'resource_node_form' => array(
      //'render element' => 'form',
       'template' => 'resource-node-form',
       'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'modulename'),
    ),
  );
}
```

And placing resource-node-form.tpl.php in modulename module folder. Cleared cache, nothing happens.

Sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out. I've used templates for existing forms from a custom theme, but I'd like to do it this way, this time. Better approach for this project I'm working on, I think.

Thanks for your answers, ask me if you need more info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {
    // Expected format: NODE_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME_node_form
    case 'resource_node_form':
      // Requires devel module to be installed.
      // See all available elements displayed using krumo.
      $dpm($form);
      break;
  }

}
```

**Update:**

Depending on the complexity of your layout, check [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) and [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) modules, as their functionality might be what you need.

You can also follow up [this](http://drupal.org/node/1092122) article if you want to do this from a tpl file. The approach is similar to what you were trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Topsitemakers! I've already done that to hide/show some fields, but I want to modify how the form gets printed. I want it to have two columns.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks Topsitemakers. I based my solution (the code I gave in my question) in that article, but it didn't work. Now I've tried again on a clean install, and it worked like a charm. So the error must be somewhere else in my site. If I find what's the problem, I'll come back here to comment. But I'll accept your answer, as it has worked on a clean install :) Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, in my hook_form_alter() I included a $form['#theme'] that created funny side effects. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try as following-

Go to your theme folder (used by your site) and create one new tpl file named as node-resource.tpl.php, then write your theming inside it.

May be it will help you.

For theming create node you can do as following-

node-resource-add.tpl.php

Comment: Hello Ankur, thanks for your answer! But wouldn't that be a template for the node? I want to theme the form that creates that node.

Comment: Check my updated answer.